# How to pass a string variable from a function into another void function

Tags: c++, dev-c++

im working on a project where I need to use a variable with same value on it on multiple functions but I dont know how. The code below doesn't work but I believe it is more easier to understand. I want to pass the string value username to a void function and store the value inside another variable called newusername then display it. I dont know how to use pointer for this, I've searched many forums and youtube videos but most of them show only passing variable from void to main not void to void or string to void.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void store(string);

string username()
{
    string username;
    
    username = "heynewuser";
    
    return username;
}

void store(string username)
{
    string newuser;
    
    newuser = username;
    cout<<newuser;
}
int main()
{
    store(username);
}
```

Comment: Please don't do pointers. c++ works on an extremely value biased premise. Dickens answer will probably guide you in a reasonable direction.

Answer (score 0):

From you question I am not fully clear, But I guess this is what you want to acieve

```
int main()
{
    store(username());
}
```

Comment: Too many different things called `username` in the OP's code.

Comment: And `store` should take its parameter by `const` ref.